# Can a song be used in a presentation for work?

Tags: copyright, fair-use, music

Does it fall under that Fair Use Act of 1976 to include a song as the intro to a presentation for work if the presentation is being given for educational/teaching purposes?

Comment: As explained in the answer below, it depends on how you're using the some for educational/teaching purposes. You can get a more detailed answer if you provide greater detail about what the presentation would be be about, what kind of song you'd be using, and how it relates to the presentation you're making.

Comment: Are you going to be doing the singing?

Comment: The presentation is about a recent software release at a tech company in front of maybe 100 employees over a zoom call along with other departments showcasing their recent work. The song would be used as a parody/spoof in a video introducing the team members who worked on the project. Like Full House or Family Matters... we're one big happy family who worked together to make a cool product not related to the song at all. This would not be on YouTube or published anywhere, but only shared internally on this zoom call.

Comment: Legality aside, you might want to consider how professional it is to include a song like this in a work presentation. If you've seen other people in your company do something like this plenty of times before, then probably nothing to worry about. But if you're trying to inject some "fun" where there usually isn't any, I would definitely reconsider.

Comment: I found this video helpful regarding some recommendations around using royalty-free music:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yov9BMZ6puM 

Also this for how that music should be credited when used in a production: https://support.epidemicsound.com/s/article/how-should-i-credit-epidemic-sound-for-the-music-that-has-been-used-in-my-production

Comment: If you're going to write new words to an existing tune and perform it yourself or arrange for someone else to perform it, just pick a song that is in the public domain.  There should be at least a few candidates from the 19th or early 20th century that would be familiar enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The educational/teaching purposes do not apply to any copyrighted work that you chose to include in the educative material that you might produce.

The educational/teaching purposes means education **refering to** or **related to** the work being used.

If  your presentation is about the musical styles of the 70s, you can use a 70s song to show how it matches those styles, its impact, relevance... But you cannot use the same song as soundtrack in a presentation about how to properly fill the X-520 form.

It also usually requires some depth. So, your presentation being just "These are some songs from the 70s" and playing a few hours would not cut it, even if it serves for some in your public to listen (learn) new songs.

Comment: From what I can tell, not everything that might be viewed as a "use" of a work is legally a use requiring a license.  Public performances of copyrighted works generally require licenses, but certain kinds of private performance do not.  If no tangible medium is produced containing the copyrighted music, playing it in a context that would not constitute a "public performance" would not require a license.  A presentation before 4,000 employees of a company would probably be different from a presentation before a group of three team members, though I don't know where the cut-off would be.

Comment: @supercat fair point, I have ammended my answer so that now it only addresses if the educational/teaching purposes can be used as a defense against copyright infringement, without denying the possibilty or other venues for legal use of the song.